# Multiple lines to single line based on my codes

Tags: python

There are many examples but I cant find the right one to solve my goal.

```
a = [["I", "have", "something"], ["she", "has", "nothing", "but", "something"]]

temp = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for word in a[i]:
        if word not in temp:
            temp.append(word)
```

My attempt:

```
temp = [word for i in range(len(a)) for word in a[i] if word not in temp]
```

Anyway to convert it to single line?
Any shorter or more smart ways to reduce the time complexity?
By the way, please no usage of library since I will be using it on the chinese words.

Comment: "I cant find the right one to solve my goal" - perhapes a good first step would be to tell us exactly what your goal *is!* :-) Is it removing duplicates from a flattened list, keeping the order?

Comment: @paxdiablo "to convert it to single line"?

Comment: It seems that you want a list of unique words in order, is that right?

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure why people insist on doing things in a single line of source code. That's exactly why languages have the ability to declare functions. Write the function (as long as it needs to be) then *call* it in a one-liner.

Comment: @paxdiablo My goal is to solve my current topic issue - to single line. Daniel Mesejo Yes, thats what I wish to have. paxdiablo Thats is another good way too but I dont plan to just write everything in single line but to learn multiple techniques and also ways to solve certain issue whenever I find. Example answers by Daniel Mesejo, I get to learn another new approach since I am a beginner. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one line (or two) and reducing the time complexity to O(n):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = [["I", "have", "something"], ["she", "has", "nothing", "but", "something"]]
r = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(k for e in a for k in e))
print(r)
```

**Output**

```
['I', 'have', 'something', 'she', 'has', 'nothing', 'but']
```

Note that this version will keep the order of the elements and works across several Python versions.

Comment: I wish there was a (built-in) `OrderedSet`.

Comment: This is good (assuming our understanding of question was correct). It removes duplicates while maintaing order.Hopefully, the original list doesnt go more thatn two levels deep.

Comment: @Anonymous Glad I could help!

Comment: Yes, its a great help! I get to realize that we could first assign each element in a list as the key for a dictionary(since dictionary cannot have more than a one key of similar value). Then assign the key-value as the same as its keys. So by this we list it then can received all the values of the dictionary. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: However, I do not understand why is this O(n) since we loop twice as well, isnt it?

Comment: Yes that's about it. It is O(n) where is  'n` the number of words. In your approach you were checking against a list, in a list the `in` operator has O(n) complexity, for `n` words O(n^2), roughly speaking.

Comment: Thank you sir but what about in your answer, can you explain a little why is it O(n) so that I could learn as well. thank you so much.

Comment: Giving values to the dict is unnecessary. Using the `fromkeys` method would be enough, e.g. `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)))`.

Comment: @Anonymous Is O(n) in regards with the number of words because checking for containment in a dictionary is O(1) so you have `n` words hence O(n)

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for the tip. Updated the answer.

Comment: I see. Just to clarify since my understanding about time complexity is that each list equivalent to n(number of words on each list)^n(deepness of the list). In my question, I loop twice so its n^2 but in your answer its also loop twice before you convert it to dictionary, right? Please correct me if I am wrong. I just wish to clear my confuse if possible

Comment: @Anonymous your approach is O(n^2) because doing `if word not in temp` is O(n), you have `n` words so n * n = O(n^2).

Comment: What about your answer? Can you explain a little please. I am still a little confuse.

Answer (score 1):

I remain continuously bemused by people who wish to reduce their code to one-liners given that this (reducing code size) was one of the basic reasons behind the existence of functions, procedures, sub-routines and other related mechanisms.

If you *have* some functionality that you want to do in one line, write a function (it's right *there* in the name, "***function***-ality") to do it then call said function on a single line.

This allows you to make the function arbitrarily complex without complicating that line of code where you want to do the work. By way of example, while an `OrderedDict` will solve your problem, the list comprehension you use will only work if you have a list of lists *exactly* two levels deep.

If you want to handle arbitrary levels, I would suggest writing a function to do it, something like:

```
def flattenDeDupe(collection):
    flatList = []
    for item in collection:
        if type(item) == type([]):
            for listItem in flattenDeDupe(item):
                flatList.append(listItem)
        else:
                if item not in flatList:
                    flatList.append(item)
    return flatList

a = [["Got", "something"], ["xyzzy"], "this", ["goes", ["much", ["deeper"]]]]

import pprint
pprint.PrettyPrinter().pprint(flattenDeDupe(a))
```

You can see that the call to the function is a one-liner as requested but you get so much more power by farming the work out to a well-written function:

```
['Got', 'something', 'xyzzy', 'this', 'goes', 'much', 'deeper']
```

Comment: Thank you so much and this really add more knowledge to me.